# Why won't my simple C# website UPDATE to db using GridView?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I have the following C# to UPDATE a record, however the textbox shows, but doesn't update to the database. Likewise, I cannot ADD a record either.

```
 private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
```

**Add:**

```
protected void AddNewMainPost(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string postID = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPostID")).Text; 
    string Name = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtSelect")).Text;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into homepageSelection(postID, selectionText) " +
    "values(@postID, @selectionText,);" +
     "select postID,selectionText, from homepageSelection";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@postID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = postID;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@selectionText", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name;
    GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
    GridView1.DataBind(); 
}
```

**Update**

```
   protected void UpdateMainPost(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        string postID = ((Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblpostID")).Text;
        string Name = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtSelec")).Text;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "update homepageSelection set selectionText=@selectionText, " +
         "where postID=@postID;" +
         "select postID,selectionText from homepageSelection";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@postID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = postID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@selectionText", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name;
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
        GridView1.DataBind(); 
    }
```

I have two fields in the database:

```
Table: homepageSelection Fields: postID and selectionText
```

Comment: Both queries contains a syntax error. Strange that you don't see any exception. Are you catching exceptions without showing them? By the way, where is the code of GetData? It seems pretty important here

Comment: command text query string looks wrong,  use try catch to see where the string is wrong.

Comment: @Steve Sorry, updated code. I wish I knew what you were talking about... Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see from your code above, you have a syntax error in both queries, but most important thing is the fact that you don't associate your command to the connection. Thus, unless you recreate the connection inside the GetData method, your command cannot be executed.

So, to fix the syntax errors

```
"select postID,selectionText from homepageSelection";
                           ^^^ comma not valid here

cmd.CommandText = @"update homepageSelection set 
                    selectionText=@selectionText" +
                                               ^^^^  again comma not valid here

cmd.CommandText = "insert into homepageSelection(postID, selectionText) " +
                  "values(@postID, @selectionText);" +
                                                 ^^^ no comma here
```

EDIT: it seems that you create the connection inside the GetData method, thus you don't need it in the two calling methods.

Comment: many thanks. However it now updates from an edit, but still can't add a new record?

Comment: Did you remove the comma also at the end of the insert into query?

Comment: I  have indeed, as per above.

Comment: Is PostID defined with the IDENTITY property on the database table? If yes then you shouldn't pass a value for it and let the database choose the value

Comment: Thanks @Steve . Is that the Primary Key? Yes, it's set to PostID